# iPhone Simulator Display

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, titanium-mobile

I'm using Titanium to build my first mobile app. Ultimately, I need to to be universal, but I'm focusing on the iPhone initially in order to learn my way around. I'm running into a problem with image display in that I need to test both the retina and non-retina display, but I can't seem to toggle between the 2.

By default, for whatever reason, my simulator launches with the "old" iPhone resolution (specifically, the combo of iOS 5 -- so location bits mostly work -- and old iPhone hardware). I see in the simulator's **Hardware** menu that I should be able to switch to iPhone (retina), but attempting to do so just aborts the simulator all together.

Is there a better way to navigate between hardware/software combinations in the simulator? Can the default configuration be changed?  Any tips or techniques would be much appreciated by this n00b to mobile dev. For whatever it's worth, the simulator version is **5.0 (272)** and, although I'm not developing native code, my XCode version is **4.2.1**.

Thanks.

Comment: Switching the simulator's hardware device type should work, so I'd say you need to reinstall XCode and the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titanium has a debugger connection running between the simulator and Titanium Studio. When you switch hardware the connection is severed and titanium aborts the simulator all together.

What you can do, is create a build in titanium studio, which builds an Xcode project (project name > build > iPhone).

Then, open this build in xCode, and run it from there. This way there is no debugging session running, but you can test it on multiple devices / OS versions.

Good luck!